# any available source codes for FPGA?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I'm new to FPGAs and I was wondering if there is any source of available designs for typical algorithms.

more specifically I'm looking for vector inner-product distance calculation or things like sorting and read and write of matrices.

I'm wondering if i need to start from scratch or I might be able to build up on previous works.

FYI, I've not yet decided on my chip or even language. I'd go with the one with more flexibility.

Comment: You should start with getting data into and out of the FPGA, without any computation in the middle.  Cause you can test that immediately, while testing computations without working I/O is impossible.

Comment: but I want to choose the language and the board based on whether I can find useful designs...

Comment: For language you basically have two options: Verilog and VHDL.  There are plenty of designs in each.  And the board is more or less unimportant.  A few designs will require a particular FPGA family, because they use vendor-specific libraries, but those should be in the minority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/), which has tons of synthesizable subsystems.

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of working with FPGAs is realizing that it's completely different to software programming.  The algorithms themselves are sort of secondary to the input, output and internal storage of information.  Starting at the basics will help and might even be faster than starting with previous works.